# No windows when I connect to my old Mac Mini via VNC

Tags: mac, windows-8, osx-lion, vncserver, realvnc

I wanted to reactivate my old Mac Mini (from 2007, OS X Lion 10.7.5) to use it for some server testing stuff.

As I don't want to add another monitor, keyboard and mouse to my desktop, I want to control the Mac via VNC, like I already did it years ago.

So I enabled screen sharing and connected to the Mac with my Windows 8 PC (RealVNC). That works fine, as long as I have a screen connected to the Mac. As soon as I disconnect the screen, all windows disappear and I only have the top and bottom bar. I can start every program, but it won't show any window. I can see popup windows (like the confirmation when I want to reboot) at the bottom left of the screen, but only the top of the popup. I can drag it in the middle, but if I let got of the mouse button, it jumps back out of sight again.

I've already searched the internet, but only found old entries that said, that it is fixed with newer versions of VNC.

Any help or alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

- Try using console in mac to set vnc settings example of commands

  Command
  Parameters
  Description
  -connect
  HOST[:PORT]
  Connects to a viewer started in the "listening"
  mode (so-called “reversed connection”).
  If port is not specified, the server
  automatically connects to
  host
  on 5500 port.
  Note: there is no notification, if connection
  can not be established.
  -disconnectall
  Disconnects all viewers from the server
  .
  -reload
  Updates settings of running TightVNC
  Server from the Windows registry.
  -shutdown
  Quits the server.
  -sharefull
  Shares virtual desktop, which consists of all
  physical displays of the machine where
  TightVNC Server runs. Shared screen area
  updates automatically, if the configuration of
  virtual desktop has been modified.
  Note: this is the default behavior of
  TightVNC Server when it is started.
  -shareprimary
  Shares primary display (display 1).
  -sharedisplay
  DISPLAY_NUMBER
  Shares display with the specified number. If
  the display with given number does not exist,
  a screen with zero dimensions will be sent

Comment: I don't know how that is supposed to help me. The connection works fine, it just looks like the Mac needs a monitor, which it doesn't have.

Comment: Link: https://github.com/mkernel/EWProxyFramebuffer - Trick your mac that display is connected

Comment: That's a pretty hardcore solution. It has to be somehow possible to control a computer, without having to install a kernel extension.

Comment: Hardware trick Link: http://soledadpenades.com/2009/02/10/mac-mini-as-a-headless-server/

Comment: http://www.pcrage2000.com/images/DVI2VGA.jpg